# How to define the sampling rate in a 3D numpy array for a multi frame TIFF file?

Tags: python, tiff, frames, frequency-analysis, numpy-ndarray

I have a multi frame TIF file which is a recording of neuronal fluorescence intensity changes over time.
The TIF file has 80 x 60 pixels and 2000 frames.

I would like to analyse the frequency of the fluorescence intensity changes for each pixel and for that I would need to define the sampling rate of the frames.
Right now I have a 3D array with (x,y) coordinates of the pixels for each frame and the number of frames in z axis projection. 
I have converted the multi frame TIF file in a 3D numpy array with the following script.

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

img = Image.open('C:/Users/Desktop/demoMovie.tif')

images = []

for i in range(2000):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        slice_ = np.zeros((80, 60))
        for j in range(slice_.shape[0]):
            for k in range(slice_.shape[1]):
                slice_[j,k] = img.getpixel((j, k))
        images.append(slice_)
    except EOFError:
        # Not enough frames in img
        break
return np.array(images)
```

Is there any way how to convert the number of the frames (z axis) in time which correspond to the frequency of the frame rate so that I can analyse the fluorescence intensity frequency for each pixel?

Thank you very much for your help.